# Nav bar button loading a view controller with no controls in it

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I am trying to create a ver simple app in iOS 7. In this I need move back and forward using `UIBarButtonItem`. But when I am pressing back button it is loading a view but not showing all UI Controls properly basically the view is empty. in  the below as I pressed any of the cell it will move to another view and load respective data.

On the pressing back button it should show earlier image but it is showing following view.

Please tell me where I am going wrong Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if your second screen is presented modally. Then you need to make an unwind segue.

Add this code to the viewcontroller that should be returned to:

```
 -(IBAction)backButtonUnwindSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{

}
```

then from your modal vc, in storyboard. Drag a segue from the "Back"-button to the Green "Exit"-icon and select the `backButtonUnwindSegue`-action

Comment: I am using segue for both cell and back button.

Comment: But how are you presenting your second screen? Is it modally? If it's a push segue then your left navigationitem should be created by the OS.

Comment: No I am using modal not push.

Comment: Thanks unwinding segue has solved my issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Check Out this:

[Passing Data example](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/)

Comment: I read this document earlier I know the basics its just an issue modal type.Thanks